# Codeigniter can't load a library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a library in the folder libraries of the codeigniter.. the route is

application/libraries/pagsegurolibrary/Pagsegurolibrary.php

And I have in the autoload file the next:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'cart', 'pagination', 'email', 'Pagsegurolibrary');
```

But when I start to use the library it shows me this error:

Unable to load the requested class: Pagsegurolibrary

I wonder why it cant load the class.. if it exists..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(
    'session',
    'cart',
    'pagination',
    'email',
    'pagsegurolibrary/pagsegurolibrary'
);
```

See there `'pagsegurolibrary/pagsegurolibrary'`

Answer (score 0):

Because the library is in a subfolder you need to include that info when loading.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'cart', 'pagination', 'email', 'pagsegurolibrary/Pagsegurolibrary');
```